# How to delete recyclerview items by id?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have displayed a data in the top view. and I don't want to display that data on recyclerview. what can I do?

---

this is my adapter for deleting items, but isn't working.

---

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

    val data = this.item?.get(position)

    val id_data= data!!.idberita.toString()

    if(sharedPrefDetailBerita.spIdberita == id_data){
        removeItem(data)
    }
}

private fun removeItem( infoData: ModelAuthor?) {
    val currPosition = this.item!!.indexOf(infoData)
    item!!.removeAt(currPosition)
    notifyItemRemoved(currPosition)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all remove it from your `list` :

```
 yourList.remove(getAdapterPosition());
```

Then use this :

```
 notifyItemRemoved(getAdapterPosition());
```

At least update your `recyclerview` with `notifyItemRangeChanged` :

```
notifyItemRangeChanged(getAdapterPosition(),yourList.size());
```

**Then your `remove function` should be change to :**

```
private fun removeItem( infoData: ModelAuthor?) {

    item.remove(getAdapterPosition())
    notifyItemRemoved(getAdapterPosition())
    notifyItemRangeChanged(getAdapterPosition(),item.size())
}
```

---

**Update :**

In `onBindViewHolder` :

```
deletedata(data,holder)
```

In out of `onBindViewHolder` pass `holder` then use it like this :

```
private fun deletedata(infoData: ModelAuthor?,holder: ViewHolder){

    item!!.removeAt(holder.adapterPosition)
    notifyItemRemoved(holder.adapterPosition)
    notifyItemRangeChanged(holder.adapterPosition, item!!.size)
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer, but it still hasn't worked. because I haven't got the position of the item to be deleted. I want to delete the item from the id_data item position. how can I get the position of the item?

Comment: This is another question i update my answer you can use `getAdapterPosition()`

Comment: not yet still erorr, after I tried this the log display `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 4, Size: 4`  I think the adapter item is still deleted all not based on the position of the item id_data.

Comment: Push your project in github and send URL for me

Comment: this my example project https://github.com/awan88/DeleteRecyclerViewById/blob/master/app/src/main/java/awan/project/deleterecyclerviewbyid/adapter/AdapterAuthor.kt

Comment: i got my problem solved, this is the way it works: https://github.com/awan88/DeleteRecyclerViewById/blob/master/app/src/main/java/awan/project/deleterecyclerviewbyid/detailpost/WPPostDetails.kt

Comment: btw, thanks for your response and answer to fix my problem.